# During conversation from UTF32 to UTF8 using UTF8-CPP I get an error "utf8::invalid_code_point"

Tags: c++, linux, utf-8, utf-32

My program get an input chinese string in utf32 encoding:

```
./myprogram 我想玩
```

I want to convert this to utf8, for this I am using library UTF8-CPP http://utfcpp.sourceforge.net

```
#include "source/utf8.h"
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    printf("argv[1] = %s \n", argv[1]);
    string str = argv[1];
    printf("str = %s \n", str);

    vector<unsigned char> utf8result;
    utf8::utf32to8(str.begin(), str.end(), back_inserter(utf8result));
```

I got the next output in terminal:

```
argv[1] = 系 
str =  D�k� 
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'utf8::invalid_code_point'
  what():  Invalid code point
```

How to fix this code, so the conversation utf32to8 will be successfull? 
What am I doing wrong, please, explain me ? 
After that I want to write received utf8 to file.

Comment: Your string is not UTF-32 to start with. Your first task is to understand what encoding you are starting with. Try printing argv[1] as a sequence of byte values. If it's still not clear post those byte values here.

Comment: hey, thanks for your answer, argv[1] is probably already in utf8 encoding, so I don't need to convert it. But I have task, that I should convert UTF32 to UTF8 and this UTF32 need to be passed to program via command line argument, like I showed in desktiption. Could you help me, what should I do ?

Answer (score 1):

The command on most `Linux` distributions passes in `UTF-8` in, so you need to convert it to `UTF-32` when you receive it and then convert it back when you print it out.

Or you could create a `UTF-32` string in the program eg. `std::u32string u32s = U"我想玩";`

```
#include "source/utf8.h"

int main()
{
    std::u32string u32s = U"我想玩";

    std::string u8s;
    utf8::utf32to8(u32s.begin(), u32s.end(), std::back_inserter(u8s));

    std::cout << u8s << '\n';
}
```

**Note:**

From `C++11` onwards you don't need to use 3rd party `UTF` libraries, the Standard Library has its own, although they are not easy to use.

You can write nicer functions to wrap them like in this answer here:

[Any good solutions for C++ string code point and code unit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43302279/any-good-solutions-for-c-string-code-point-and-code-unit/43302460#43302460)

Comment: Not sure how a good idea is to use the standard library for that, because the "Locale-independent unicode conversion facets" are already deprecated in C++17.

Comment: @AndreiAndrey The current functions won't be removed until well after the replacement is in place. And also by wrapping the standard functions in user friendly functions the way I have in the linked answer you are completely protected. You simply replace the code in the rapper functions. Any software you write only needs a slight adjustment in one place. So I don't see a problem.

Comment: @AndreiAndrey I feel it is much better tracking what happens in the Standard Library than the potential changes in a *third party library*. The Standards committee are trying harder than anyone to maintain backward compatibility.

Comment: I agree with what you are saying. I just wanted to point out it's far from the ideal solution.

Comment: @AndreiAndrey It is frustrating they finally put some unicode support in and then change it right after. From what I have seen of the changes, though, they don't look so large. IIRC it is more like replacing what's there with something similar but less hard-coded.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely `argv[1]` is already stored with Utf-8 encoding. Because this is default way to handle Unicode in Linux. Note that utf32 characters can not be properly represented by `std::string` or by C-style null-terminated array of `char` because every item occupies 4 bytes.