# UTF8 char array to std::wstring

Tags: c++, unicode, utf-8, x11, xcb

I just trying to get x11 window title, and store it in std::wstring. I use such command to get the title

```
auto req_title = xcb_get_property(conn, 0, window, XCB_ATOM_WM_NAME, XCB_GET_PROPERTY_TYPE_ANY, 0, 100);
auto res_title = xcb_get_property_reply(conn, req_title, nullptr);
```

After that, I can get title stored in char array. How can I convert this array to wstring?

Comment: This answer may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43302279/any-good-solutions-for-c-string-code-point-and-code-unit/43302460#43302460

Comment: Why? What can you possibly do with a wchar array on a unix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Current solution

You can use [**`std::wstring_convert`**](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/locale/wstring_convert/) to convert a `string` to or from `wstring`,  using a [`codecvt`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/locale/codecvt/?kw=codecvt) to specify the conversion to be performed.

Example of use:

```
string so=u8"Jérôme Ângle"; 
wstring st; 
wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>,wchar_t> converter;
st = converter.from_bytes(so);
```

If you have a c-string (array of char), the overloads of `from_bytes()` will do exactly what you want:

```
char p[]=u8"Jérôme Ângle";
wstring ws = converter.from_bytes(p);
```

[Online demo](https://ideone.com/nrO1qT)

### Is it sustainable ?

As pointed out in the comments, [C++17 has deprecated](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/p0636r0.html) `codecvt` and the `wstring_convert` utility:

> These features are hard to use correctly, and there
>   are doubts whether they are even specified correctly. Users should use
>   dedicated text-processing libraries instead.

In addition, a `wstring` is based on `wchar_t` which has a very different encoding on linux systems and on windows systems.

So the first question would be to ask why a `wstring` is needed at all, and why not just keep [utf-8 everywhere](http://utf8everywhere.org).

Depending on the reasons, you may consider to use:

- [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/home) and its [`UnicodeString`](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/classicu_1_1UnicodeString.html) for a full, in-depth, unicode support
- [boost.locale](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/locale/doc/html/charset_handling.html) an its `to_utf` or [`utf_to_utf`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/locale/doc/html/group__codepage.html#gaf0ad39959911b000706e0538ec059d44), for common unicode related tasks.
- [utf8-cpp](http://utfcpp.sourceforge.net) for working with utf8 strings the unicode way (attention, seems not maintained).

Comment: Note wstring_convert and wbuffer_convert and codecvt_utf8 are all deprecated in C++17.

Comment: `from_bytes()` has overloads that accept a null-terminated `char*` string, and two `char*` iterators denoting a range, so you don't need to wrap your `char` data in a temporary `std::string` if it didn't start life that way to begin with.

Comment: @Christophe IMO just wrap the `std::wstring_convert` code in neat little functions (eg. `utf8_to_ws(...)` & `ws_to_utf8(...)`) Then you don't spread its use throughout the applications. Then when it is changed you only have to change one function, not all your code.

Comment: @RemyLebeau thanks for pointing this out! I've edited accordingly.

Comment: @Galik wise idea !  Especially when I read "*Users should use dedicated text-processing libraries instead.*" in a [working paper of the standard committee](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/p0636r0.html)

Comment: @n.m. I suppose you mean [utf-8 everywhere](http://utf8everywhere.org) :-)

Comment: utf-8 everywhere is an excellent paper indeed, but you don't have to follow it religiously, just move away from wchar_t, that's all.

Comment: I'm on c++17 this won't compile. I need wchar_t because i'm using windows libraries. There must be a solution that compiles on c++17 visual studio and this isn't it.